# How do I install Mist from the pre-built binaries on 32-bit Linux?

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm attempting to install Mist (i.e. the Wallet) on a fresh Linux install (Ubuntu 14.04). I've already got it running on other machines of different platforms.

Instead of following the [CLI instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/mist), I'm being lazy and downloading the pre-built binary from the [Releases](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) page, with the idea being that I can just run the executable and it'll create me a node. (Which is what the documentation *says* should happen... )

After downloading the binary and running the `Ethereum-wallet` executable, it's giving me the following GUI pop-up:

[image]

("No Ethereum node binary found!")

Running from the command line instead, I get the following output:

```
~/Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2$ sudo ./Ethereum-Wallet 
[2016-04-30 19:11:12.406] [INFO] main - Starting in Wallet mode
[2016-04-30 19:11:12.742] [WARN] nodeConnector - NODECONNECTOR ERROR { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc' }
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
[2016-04-30 19:11:13.110] [INFO] ipcCommunicator - Backend language set to:  en
[2016-04-30 19:11:13.167] [WARN] nodeConnector - NODECONNECTOR ERROR { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc' }
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /home/richard/.ethereum/geth.ipc
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.091] [INFO] main - Node type:  geth
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.092] [INFO] main - Network:  main
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.094] [INFO] ethereumNodes - Start node from /home/richard/Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2/resources/node/geth/geth
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.114] [INFO] ethereumNodes - Stopping nodes...
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.114] [INFO] ethereumNodes - Starting geth node...
[2016-04-30 19:11:14.130] [INFO] ethereumNodes - Stopping nodes...
```

What am I doing wrong? Was I wrong to assume the node would be set-up automatically, and that I have to do so first as a separate task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geth` is not included in the 32 bit Linux Ethereum Wallet packages (I've checked the current version 0-7-2 and 0-6-1):

```
user@Kumquat:~/EthereumWallet$ unzip -t Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2.zip | grep resources
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2/resources/   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2/resources/app.asar   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2/resources/atom.asar   OK
```

But it is included in the 64 bit Linux package:

```
user@Kumquat:~/EthereumWallet$ unzip -t Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2.zip | grep resources
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/app.asar   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/atom.asar   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/node/   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/node/geth/   OK
    testing: Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-2/resources/node/geth/geth   OK
```

It seems that `geth` is normally not included in the 32 bit Linux packages.

If you have a 32 bit Ubuntu Linux installation, you will have to try installing `geth` using (from [Installation Instructions for Ubuntu - Installing from PPA](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
# Next line only if you want the dev version
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

The `ethereum` package above does seem to have the 32-bit version available (see [Ethereum - publishing details](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+sourcepub/6279105/+listing-archive-extra) - it's the i386 version).

Comment: Sorry - I tried without `sudo` first and got the same output. (All console logs exactly the same.) This was a second attempt with `sudo`. The `resources/` folder only contains 2 files: `app.asar` and `atom.asar`. I've checked the MD5 of the `.zip` file. The `~/.ethereum` folder doesn't exist - there are no previous instances of geth running.

Comment: ...which would seem to point to the need to install `geth` first as a separate step.

Comment: I just checked `Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-7-2.zip` and it does not have the `geth` binaries included. I'm surprised. `geth` is included in the 64 bit linux package. Are you running on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: It's running 32-bit Ubuntu - I can't remember my reasoning, but possibly because the machine's a couple of years old (though 64-bit hardware... ). I'll chuck a 64-bit version on it and use the 64-bit EW. (Or install geth separately.) Thanks for your help! :)