# If I installed Mist, do I also need to install geth separately?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

Under Mac when I try to run "geth", I get the error "command not found".

Mist is installed and in use..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Mist includes geth.

The reason you're getting the `command not found` error is because geth is not recognized by your command line path.  Running Mist will automatically start the local copy of geth.

Comment: Perhaps not completely relevant for the OP, but 32-bit Linux Mist doesn't include geth. (Unsure about 32-bit Windows.)

Comment: Even though mist includes geth, don't you still need to install the command line interface in order to run `geth` commands?

Comment: @tayvano I haven't tried it, but I assume you can invoke the geth application included with mist that same as the standalone version.  I don't believe there's a difference between the two versions

Comment: @dbryson I believe you are right. I think the only issue is that sometimes users type `geth --fast` and get a `command not found`. It's not because geth isn't installed, it's because the command line interface isn't installed so typing `geth...` isn't recognized / calling the installed geth.

Comment: @tayvano Right.  It's simply because the path to the Mist version of geth is not recognized by the command line terminal.  Adding the full path to it in your bashrc scripts etc... should fix that

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I've just been telling people install geth which ends up accomplishing the same thing, but just the path would be way easier. Thank you!

Comment: @tayvano No problem. BTW nice work on MyEtherWallet

Comment: thanks. where is then typically geth is located on Mac after I installed Mist ?

Comment: @MaksimRavnovesov on OS X if you installed Mist in Applications, it should be at `/Application/EthereumWallet/Contents/Frameworks/node/geth`

Comment: @dbryson Hmm. Strange, I don't have it. I searched the whole HDD for the folder "EthereumWallet" and "geth" and didn't find it. There is an "Ethereum-Wallet.app" but that's all. A bit confused now.. Do I yet need to install the "geth" separately ?

Comment: @MaksimRavnovesov If you're on OS X you need to right click on Ethereum-Wallet and select "package contents"  in there you'll find geth

Comment: thanks @dbryson, I see it now there. In case I want to use it separately in the terminal, what should i do? copy the "geth" from the package somewhere separately?

Answer (score 4):

[An addendum to the main answer concerning the Mac implementation of Geth.]

**Not all implementations of Mist explicitly include Geth.**

If you're using the [pre-built packages](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) on the Releases page, the 32-bit versions for Linux and Windows don't include Geth, whereas the 64-bit versions do. (As does the Mac version.) In the case of the 32-bit versions, Geth should be installed separately.

See this previous thread: [How do I install Mist from the pre-built binaries on 32-bit Linux?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/how-do-i-install-mist-from-the-pre-built-binaries-on-32-bit-linux)

Comment: I just downloaded Mist-win64-0.8.6 and it looks like geth is no longer included; just eth?